# How do I make my bootstrap carousel appear only when hovering over a piece of text?

Tags: html, css, carousel, display

Please help! I have tried to find this seemingly straightforward function for days and can only find information related to the hidden display of bootstrap controls. How can I apply the hidden display to the entire bootstrap carousel with either css or java? I'd like for the carousel to only appear when the mouse hovers over a piece of text. Please let me know! Thank you.

Comment: Or java? Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example because it's hard to help you without the proper information.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some assumptions based on your question. You are using Bootstrap. So I assume you are also using jQuery as it is a dependency. Why don't use jQuery to remove the no-display class when hovering the text.

```
<script>
    $( "#text-container" )
        .on( "mouseenter", function() {
            $( "#carrousel" ).removeClass( "no-display" );
        })
        .on( "mouseleave", function() {
            $( "#carrousel" ).addClass( "no-display" );
        });
</script>
```

text-container should be used to target the text container.
carrousel should be used to target the carousel container.

Check this page for more information https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Tip: next time, tell us more about the tech you are using.